# How to delete old runs in ATU reporter?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi i am newbie to `ATU reporter`, i am using this connection with TestNG so **how to delete my old runs(Run1,Run2,...etc)**tried searching on Google still didn't get any result, please help.

Comment: Do you have access to ATU Reports/Results directory? As you need to manually delete some data in files located in this directory.

Comment: @MosamMehta ya i have access to reports drirectory, i tried deleting folder itself still it is showing old Runs also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps to delete previous runs :

Go to `/ATU Reports/Results` directory and modify below files.

- **barChart.js** file : Remove values for variables `s1,s2,s3 and ticks`. After removing values, variables should be like `var s1 = [];`
- **ConsolidatedPage.html** file : Remove all lines containing Run #number values having parameter `<li class>` and one parameter `<li style>`. For an example,
  `<li class="menuStyle"><a href="Run_1\CurrentRun.html" >Run 1 </a></li>`
  Remove this line for all runs.
  Remove `<li style>` line for latest run.
- **LineChart.js** file : Remove values for variable `line1, line2, line3` and `ticks` and set values to `[]` for all variables.
- **Settings.properties** file : Remove values for `skippedList, failedList, passedList and Run`.

After performing these steps, run your tests and verify the report.

Answer (score -1):

After followed the ran new test, new Folders are created for ATU Reports, Please do needful

[image]